# Joomla 3.2.2 - frontend connection problems, backend working perfect

Tags: joomla, problem

First of all, I'd like to say hello to everybody in this great community :) Countless times before, I was able to find my way out of a problem thanks to you. But now, I can't find any similar topic to my problem.

It started 5 days ago with frontend errors - Internal 500 or connection was reset. Every time after very long waiting. I thought that it's some problem on the provider side, they checked, said everything was fine, they checked two times. The second time they suggested I clean my browser cache. I did, and my site worked great. For a minute. It allowed one or two clicks in articles and... again, same old story. Then, it became even worse - even after cleaning the browser cache, I have problems to launch the frontend. Backend works perfect, I can edit, save and so on every article, module, and so on. When frontend finally manages to open, it reflects changes. So... it's very strange to me.

That was the situation till two days ago, when things got a bit better.

Now - no 500 internals or "connection was reset" during loading. Presently it looks like that : there is longer than average "awaiting for connection" time, and when finally download starts, it's very fast. Sometimes this waiting is 5, sometimes 10 seconds, which is way too long. I tried disabling modules, compressing js & css, but nothing helped to come to real awaiting time which is normally below 1s on other sites.

Hosting keeps claiming that it's not their fault, and suggested it's some module or extension causing problems, but as I said, I tried disabling every module one by one, with no result.

Did anybody encounter something like that?

By the way, other websites on same hosting and same Joomla version work just fine. Template? For the first two days it was ok, so it's not template either. I tried to change options of SEF links, url rewriting - nothing. It's driving me mad.

Additionaly, I created an account on Pingdom, and they show that my page loads worse than 70-80% of other websites. I also set checking each minute and letting me know via sms (it's free up to 20 smses) if the site is offline more than 5 minutes in a row - and I get one-two such smses daily.

Thank you in advance for your imput, maybe somebody has to look at this with a clear head.

Joomla version is 3.2.2

Cheers and thank you in advance,

Artur

Comment: Is is all pages or certain types of pages? Also is this when logged in or guest?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Y Slow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/), a Firefox extension.

You can also use a Chrome extension available from [their website](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/).

Y Slow will break down the elements that make up your front end into a graph, which will show you what is causing the longest delays to page load time.